# how to use swagger in django

Tags: django, swagger

I'm a beginner of swagger, i have a website written in django(already done), and i want to use swagger to exhibit my apis. I'v read the docs in swagger.io for days, but I still need more help.

I also tried the Django REST Swagger(https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger). I tried the basic example (http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#basic-example-with-a-viewset), but it still not work.

Maybe i did something wrong, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The Django Rest Swagger package is very useful for this.

Did you put 'rest_framework_swagger' into your INSTALLED_APPS setting?

If you did, just put the `url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls'))` in the urls.py where you are exposing your API endpoints and it should display all the other url's that you have in that file.

Comment: sure, i put 'rest_framework_swagger' into  INSTALLED_APPS, and include('rest_framework_swagger.urls') in my urls.py, but when i open the corresponding url, i can't see my apis.